# Determine time complexity when inner loop runs twice of outer loop variable

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am novice in analyzing time complexity.some one can help me with the time complexity of below algorithm?

```
public void test(int n)
{
  int i=1;

   while(i<n)
   {
      int j=0; 
      while (j<n)
      {
         j=j+(2*i);
      }

     i=i*2;
   }
}
```

outer loop will run log(n) times.How many times the inner loop will run. How can we calculate the frequency of inner loop in terms of "n" because it depends on variable "i" .

Can someone help to find time complexity of above code.

Answer (score 0):

Outer loop will run for `log(n)` times.

Say `n = 32`. So inner loop will run for:

- `n/2` for `i = 1`
- `n/4` for `i = 2`
- `n/8` for `i = 3`
- `1` for `i = 31`

So this geometric series its sum will be `<= 2n`.

i.e `n/2 + n/4 + ..... + 1 <= 2n`.

So time complexity of above algorithm is

```
logn + 2n
```

which is `O(n)`.